# Value of text field/ text box does NOT change permanently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textfield

Here is my HTML,

Button and Text Field are declared

The button calls a function:

```
<div>
<form>
    <button onclick="myFunction2()">Click Here</button>
    <input type="text" name="textbox" id="text" style="width: 10px"/>
</form>
```

Here I simply declare some variables (JAVASCRIPT):

```
var integers = {
        'one': 1,
        'two': 2,
        'three': 3,
        'fiveHundred': 500,
    }
```

I attempt to change the text field value here:

```
function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("text").value = integers["one"];
    }
```

The goal is for the text field to say 1, it does however the number 1 appears for only a split second.

Please excuse my code as I am just learning.

Comment: If something appears for a split second inside a form, it's a good bet the form submits, and the page reloads.

Comment: To be clearer, you need to change the button to `<button onclick="myFunction2()" type="button">Click Here</button>`

Answer (score 0):

```
  <form>
    <button onclick="myFunction2()" type="button">Click Here</button>
    <input type="text" name="textbox" id="text" style="width: 100px"/>
  </form>
```